# pseudo-arc length continuation petsc4py

Tags: python, continuation, petsc, trilinos

I have been a user of pseudo arc-length continuation, nonlinear solvers... in Trilinos LOCA (c++) for years but I recently come across the python package petsc4py. This simplified a lot my programming for a minor decrease in speed.

The only missing class of petsc4py is a pseudo-arclength continuation solver. PETSC has a pseudo-time stepper solver but this is not nearly as useful as turning points break down the algorithm.

Trilinos LOCA has a wrapper for PETSC but I was looking for a solution where the problem is specified in python (from petsc4py) rather than in c or c++.

Hence, I am looking for a class written in petsc4py, or callable from petsc4py, implementing pseudo-arclength continuation.

Thank your very much.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. To me this question looks like a question asking to recommend a tool or a library. Such questions are explicitly specified as off-topic (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please consider reformulating the question to identify a specific programming problem. Btw, could pytrilinos help you out there?

Comment: Hello! I reformulate then: "Does anyone has a class in petsc4py (or PETSc) to perform arc-length continuation?". Let me comment en pyTrilinos. pyLOCA (for continuation) is currently disabled from pyTrilinos, so no real solution there. Moreover, I would have to entirely reprogram my problem in the Trilinos setting from scratch.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about availability of specific library extensions. Answering it would require a certain level of understanding of scientific computing applications. http://scicomp.stackexchange.com is a better forum for this kind of questions.